# What's the longest non-winning string in Insertion Ghost?

Tags: word

The game [Ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_%28game%29) is a game where players take turns appending letters to the end of a word. The first person to form a complete word with at least four letters, or give a string of a letters that no word begins with, loses.

An example game might go:

> Player 1: A
>   Player 2: AC
>   Player 1: ACC
>   Player 2: ACCO
>   Player 1: ACCOM
>   Player 2: ACCOMP
>   Player 1: ACCOMPA
>   Player 2: ACCOMPAN

At this point, player 1 realizes he loses because all variants of ACCOMPANY (all of which begin with ACCOMPANI-) have an odd number of letters. If he'd gone with ACCOMPL instead of ACCOMPA on his fourth turn, he could have forced player 2 to spell ACCOMPLISH or ACCOMPLICE or ACCOMPLETIVE, all of which have an *even* number of letters, thereby winning.

Therefore, we call ACCOMP a *non-winning string* for Player 1, in which there are both odd-length and even-length words that begin with that string, and therefore it's not a sure thing that Player 1 wins yet. (He many have the *winning strategy* by choosing ACCOMPL, but he still has to make the right choice in order to win here.)

---

A friend and I came up with a variant in middle school in which you could insert a letter anywhere within the word itself. We called it *Insertion Ghost*
due to its insertion mechanic (the Wikipedia article linked above calls it Xghost or Superduperghost and attributes it to a man named Daniel Asimov).

In this game, a string like XVZ is valid because you can still make the word E**X**TRA**V**AGAN**Z**A out of it. Thus, the potential for words, and the capacity for strategic thinking, is much larger.

A game might go like this:

> Player 1: X
>   Player 2: XF (thinking of "EXFOLIATE")
>   Player 3: XFD (thinking of "EXFOLIATED")
>   Player 4: XMFD (now thinking of "EXEMPLIFIED")
>   Player 5: ... ... ... EXMFD (also thinking of "EXEMPLIFIED", but stalling)

As you can see, the target words get convoluted really quickly, and even switch a lot of letters almost all the way (the change from EXFOLIATED to EXEMPLIFIED being the target word inserted five letters between the X and the F that weren't there before, just to change the target word), and it becomes much harder to determine whether you've won in advance or not. An example of a five-letter non-winning string might be CLAMT - both CLAIMANT (8) and EXCLAMATION (11) are possible target words.

What's the *longest* non-winning string (i.e. a string that can have both odd-length and even-length target words) in this variant, for either player?

---

For the purpose of this question, our word list is the [2012 CSW](http://www.scrabbleplayers.org/w/Collins_Scrabble_Words_2012_Edition).

Comment: So no infinity with PHP.... :(

Comment: Note: OED might be a bad idea because it's behind a paywall. But I'll see if I can find a better one. If not, we'll have to limit it to words of length 15 or less, which sorta sucks.

Comment: How about [Moby](http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mwords.html) as recommended over on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11572668/4475014)?

Comment: Do I understand that the word must be as least 4 characters long?

Comment: SOWPODS was superseded by CSW a while ago.

Comment: Also, it looks like Moby hasn't been updated in 15 years. I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @EngineerToast: Yes, the target word must be at least four letters long.

Comment: Would it be viable to have letters for 1 word that might have 2+ suffixes?

Comment: Please can I check I've understood? We're looking for the longest string of letters that isn't a word but can have letters added to it to make an odd-length word and can have letters added to it to make an even length word? Is the plural of the odd/even an acceptable even/odd (if you see what I mean by that)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @Avon.

Comment: @Joe Z. With all due respect I don't think it's very clear in the question because of the game story around it. Are you looking for: the longest possible string of letters that is not a word but when any number of other letters is added anywhere to it does make a word (A) AND when any other number of letters is added to anywhere to it makes another word (B) AND where total lengths of A and B are odd (i.e. one is odd, one is even)? (From the answer/discussion below I gather that is what is being asked.)

Comment: Let me try again: If you have a string of letters S that is not a word, and you can insert two different sets of letters to create two words A and B, where A is odd length and B is even length, then S is a non-winning string.

Comment: Great thanks (and by insert I take it you mean insert, append, prepend and any combination anywhere along the string). And you mentioned 15 letters maximum before the previous answer got deleted. Is that still the case? It has not been put into the question at the time of writing that I can see.

Comment: @Avon: An additional requirement is that it must be possible to form words (A) and (B) by adding letters in a sequence such that none of the intermediate letter strings are also words.

Comment: @supercat and presumably from letter 1 to the string S too. But I expect (haven't tried) that that would be pretty trivial in almost all cases (e.g. start with nothing but the consonants).

Comment: @Avon: It probably is trivial in the majority of cases, but there might be some where it matters.

Comment: @Avon: The 15-letter maximum is only because the word list in use is the CSW, which only contains words usable in Scrabble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the CSW only contains words with 15 letters or less, it's quite trivial. I go for one of many:

> ALLEGORISATIO (13 letters, targets ALLEGORISATION and ALLEGORISATIONS)

which I presume is in the 2012 CSW.

Comment: I guess it's the same no matter what word length I choose. *sigh*

Comment: @JoeZ. I thought something like this would happen....I guess Puzzling has become too smart :p

Comment: @Joe Z It's this damned internet makes finding these answers too easy. Maybe limit it to letters inserted - not appended or prepended - might make it a little trickier but then it's not directly based on your Insertion Ghost game and has less value.

Comment: @Joe Z. I am still a little confused about the game rules though. Is this not a winning word because other player has to make a word? Or does the other player not lose if you can then make another word it and they can't from that? This answer fits the "string of letters S that is not a word, and you can insert two different sets of letters to create two words A and B, where A is odd length and B is even length" challenge but does it fit the game rules definition of a non-winning (distinct from losing??) word? (Is that summary of the challenge, in fact, a little wrong?)

Comment: No, I'm lamenting the fact that it *is* a winning word because the strategy to get it hasn't changed at all.